# custom UIAlertView with UITextFields and UITextViews

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitextfield, uialertview

I want to make an `UIAlertView` in which there is a `UITextField` and `UITextView` displaying some 5 - 6 lines.I tried creating the views and adding it as subviews but it overlaps the alert view's buttons. On resizing the alert view the buttons do not shift downwards. Also I need to set different background and stuff for it. That is I need to make an custom alert view. I am new to iPhone programming. Please provide a way to do this.

Comment: Or, just create a modal view customized exactly the way that you like it....

Answer (score 4):

You really can't make a custom alert view because Apple has decided it's something they don't want us messing with. If you can live with only one text field in the alert and the stock background color you can use `setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput` to put a text field into the alert.

```
UIAlertView *myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
[myAlertView setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput];
[myAlertView show];
```

However, if you do really want to make these changes, you'll have to make your own out of a `UIView` and dress it up to look like an alert view. Here's a rough example:

```
- (IBAction)customAlert:(UIButton *)sender
{
    UIView *myCustomView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 100, 280, 300)];
    [myCustomView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.9f green:0.0f blue:0.0f alpha:0.8f]];
    [myCustomView setAlpha:0.0f];

    UIButton *dismissButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [dismissButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissCustomView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [dismissButton setTitle:@"Close" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [dismissButton setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 250, 240, 40)];
    [myCustomView addSubview:dismissButton];

    UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 240, 35)];
    [textField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
    [myCustomView addSubview:textField];

    UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 75, 240, 150)];
    [myCustomView addSubview:textView];

    [self.view addSubview:myCustomView];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2f animations:^{
        [myCustomView setAlpha:1.0f];
    }];
}

- (void)dismissCustomView:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2f animations:^{
        [sender.superview setAlpha:0.0f];
    }completion:^(BOOL done){
        [sender.superview removeFromSuperview];
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the same what you do and in order to move buttons down, use multiple '\n' characters as message text.

For example:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
        initWithTitle: @"Your title"
        message: @"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"
        delegate: nil
        cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
        otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
```

Answer (score 0):

For the alert message text, just add a bunch of line break characters like this:

```
@"The alert message.\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the best way to do that is to create a class which is a subclass of `UIAlertView`, but `UIAlertView`class reference says **The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.**

It's been a while I needed to create a popup login, I followed this [tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-5-sdk-uialertview-text-input-and-validation/). It's very useful, then i've read some post that people complaining that their apps got rejected, because of using a subclass of `UIAlertView`. The interesting part is at that time, youtube app was using a popup login control that looks like that they've used a subclass of `UIAlertView`, but maybe that they created from scratch and subclass of `UIView`. I think it's worth to give a shot.